# Integral $\int (t^2 - 1)^{a} \cdot t^{b} \cdot \log(t)\,dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms, indefinite-integrals, hypergeometric-function

The Integral $\int (t^2 - 1)^{a} \cdot t^{b} \cdot \log(t)\,dt$ has the following solution in terms of hypergeometric functions according to Wolfram:

[image]

The solution has also been check extensively. I have tried to use integration by parts, but did not find any references on integral leading to the hypergeometric function with my resources.

Does anyone know how to get this final solution in terms of the two hypergeometric functions?

Comment: The first thing that stands out is that$$\frac {\partial}{\partial b}t^b=t^b\log t$$So we can write your integral as$$\mathcal{I}=\frac {\partial}{\partial b}\int dt\,(t^2-1)^a t^b$$

Comment: @Vic Not quite $$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}t^b = bt^{b-1}$$

Comment: @Dylan, I have done some search on the Feynman's trick, but it is not that obvious to me, could you elaborate on using Feynman's trick in this problem.

Comment: Define $F(b)$ as your integral. Then you have $F'(b)$ as the second integral in the above comment. You'll also need to find $F(0)$ by integrating $$ \int (t^2-1)^a \ln t\ dt $$. Then just integrate back $F'(b)$ and find the constant

Comment: I don't have any hints for you. I'm just elaborating on the first comment.

Comment: @YuriyS, yes, you are absolutely right, then the problem becomes proving $uv$ is the first term involving $_{2}F_{1}(\cdot)$, and $\int v\,du$ is the second term involving $_{3}F_{2}(\cdot)$, which is simpler but still not straightforward, especially proving the second term.

Comment: @YuriyS, all of the three parameters(t, a, b) are positive, do you think it is necessary to restrict $t >1$ to have the shown solution?

Comment: @Vic, I don't think so, but in some cases you would have complex value of the integral if $|t|<1$

Comment: @YuriyS, that´s true. It is interesting that the solution to such a simple integral is so complicate. When trying to solve the integral, I even find that solving the integral like $\int (t^2 −1)^{a}\,dt$ using hypergeomtric function is nontrivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got another answer in terms of hypergeometric functions which is also correct numerically and can be likely transformed into the answer Wolfram gives.

1. The answer is (I omit the constant):

> $$\int t^b (t^2-1)^a \ln t~dt= \\ = \frac{t^{2a+b+1}}{2a+b+1} \bigg( (\ln t) {_2 F_1} \left(-a,-a-\frac{b+1}{2};-a-\frac{b-1}{2}; \frac{1}{t^2} \right) - \\ - \frac{1}{2a+b+1} {_3 F_2} \left(-a,-a-\frac{b+1}{2},-a-\frac{b+1}{2};-a-\frac{b-1}{2},-a-\frac{b-1}{2}; \frac{1}{t^2} \right) \bigg)$$

2. The formulas used (per Wikipedia [Hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) and [Generalized hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function)):

$$\mathrm {B} (b,c-b)\,_{2}F_{1}(a,b;c;z)=\int _{0}^{1}x^{b-1}(1-x)^{c-b-1}(1-zx)^{-a}\,dx$$

$$_{A+1}F_{B+1}\left[{\begin{array}{c}a_{1},\ldots ,a_{A},c\\b_{1},\ldots ,b_{B},d\end{array}};z\right]={\frac {\Gamma (d)}{\Gamma (c)\Gamma (d-c)}}\int _{0}^{1}t^{c-1}(1-t)_{}^{d-c-1}\ {}_{A}F_{B}\left[{\begin{array}{c}a_{1},\ldots ,a_{A}\\b_{1},\ldots ,b_{B}\end{array}};tz\right]dt$$

3. The solution.

   - First, we will find the integral (I have chosen the limits so we can easily trace the substitutions, the lower, constant limit can be arbitrary):

$$\int^{t_0}_1 t^b (t^2-1)^a~dt$$

We can do that by changing the variable the following way:

$$\frac{1}{t} = x \quad \to \quad x^2=y \quad \to \quad y=\frac{z}{t_0^2}$$

If you perform every substitution correctly, you will find two integrals in the form given by Wikipedia:

$$\int^{t_0}_1 t^b (t^2-1)^a~dt= \\ = - \frac{t_0^{2a+b+1}}{2} \int_0^1 \left(1-\frac{1}{t_0^2} z \right)^a z^{-a-(b+3)/2} dz+\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \left(1- y \right)^a y^{-a-(b+3)/2} dy$$

The last expression is just a constant, the first one gives the hypergeometric function (you will also need to brush up on the properties of Beta function):

$$\int^{t_0}_1 t^b (t^2-1)^a~dt= \\ = \frac{t_0^{2a+b+1}}{2a+b+1} {_2 F_1} \left(-a,-a-\frac{b+1}{2};-a-\frac{b-1}{2}; \frac{1}{t_0^2} \right)+\text{const}$$

- Now we use the integration by parts formula:

$$\int t^b (t^2-1)^a \ln t~dt= \ln t~\int t^b (t^2-1)^a ~dt-\int \frac{1}{t} \int t_1^b (t_1^2-1)^a ~dt_1~dt$$

- We need to find the integral:

$$\int t^{2a+b} {_2 F_1} \left(-a,-a-\frac{b+1}{2};-a-\frac{b-1}{2}; \frac{1}{t^2} \right) dt$$

We use the same substitutions as above to transform this integral to the form required by the second formula from Wikipedia and obtain the answer.

---

Here's an example of numerical confirmation that the expression is correct:

[image]

Comment: There was a typo in the answer, of course it's ${_3 F_2}$

Comment: that's really brilliant, we usually solve definite integral by using its antiderivative, and here it goes the opposite way, thumbs-up :)

Comment: may I know which property of Beta function have you used to obtain the final answer, as Beta function is linked with Gamma function and it seems that there is no direct relationship between the Beta function and the expression (2a+b+1). Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Vic, I think it's the property $B(1,x)=\frac{1}{x}$, thought I'm not sure, I don't remember the details of this calculation

Comment: yep, that's it and everything is crystal clear now, thanks a lot.

Comment: hi Yuriy, I have a new problem on an integral involving K function occurs, which I have worked on it for two days but still do not have a clue. Could you have a look and see if you have any thoughts (https://bit.ly/2qael0y)? Thanks a lot in advance.